# C++/ Store data from a file txt to an object

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Let's say I've got a txt file with mutiple line exemple:

jeremy(thats the name) 0952966(thats the id) 5(nb of grades) 10 20 12 (grades)

the question is how to isolated each things like the name the id and the grade into some attributes.
When I read the file I can isolated some of the things with getLine but I cannot store it properly into attributes or a container.

Thank you

here's what my student class looks like right now:

```
#ifndef ETUDIANT_H
#define ETUDIANT_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Etudiant {


private:
    Etudiant(string un_nom, long un_id);

    string nom;
    long id;
    int nb_note;
    vector<int> notes;
public:
    Etudiant(string n, string i, int nb) {
        nom = n;
        id = i;
        nb_note = nb
    }
    Etudiant() {
        nom = "";
        id = "";
        nb_note = "";
    }
    string obtenirNom() { return nom; }

    long obtenirId() { return id; }

    int obtenirNbNote() { return nb_note; }

    void ajoutNote(int note) {
        notes.push_back(note);
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Is your data on one line like `jeremy 0952966 5 10 20 12` or is it on multiple lines? An example of a couple items of actual data without (commentary) would help. You should add your current reading code to your question. Work on a [mcve].

Comment: that would be on one line and theres mutiple similar line like this under with different name id nb_grade grade

Comment: jeremy 0952966 3 10 20 12  /
steve  1010100 2 20 15  /
emily  2022221 5 12 13 19 4 9

Comment: You can edit additional data into the question. Are the names always a single word?

Comment: Are you familiar with the extraction operator (`>>`)?

Comment: If you don't want to design your own serialization format, you'd better try JSON,XML...